# is_file returns TRUE but include fails on same file

Tags: php

When I run the following script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<?php
echo get_include_path(), "\n";

var_dump(is_file('/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php'));
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following output on the rendered page:

```
.:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/PEAR bool(true)
```

However, if I run this script:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<?php
echo get_include_path(), "\n";

var_dump(is_file('/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php'));

#### NEW SECTION ####

if (include(''/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php'') == 'OK') {
echo 'INCLUDE OK, "\n"';
} else { echo 'INCLUDE FAILED \n' ; }

#### END NEW SECTION ####

?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following output:

```
.:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/PEAR bool(true) INCLUDE FAILED \n
```

Why would the include fail if the file is said to exist already?

uname output in case it is helpful:

```
Darwin 70cd606c7510 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Thank you for your help.

John

Comment: `''/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php''` is a syntax error. Are you sure that's it?

Answer (score 3):

You should have read [Example #4 on the PHP help page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-129):

```
<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Also, are the double single quotes in your original code a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @animuson and to everyone who read my post.  I removed the double quotes and made the change you suggested, and I still get the same result (boolean returns true but the include does not return 'OK').  See updated code below:  `<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<?php
echo get_include_path(), "\n";

var_dump(is_file('/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php'));

#### NEW SECTION ####

if (include '/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php' == 'OK') {
echo 'INCLUDE OK, "\n"';
} else { echo 'INCLUDE FAILED \n' ; }

#### END NEW SECTION ####

?>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Does that file actually return 'OK'? An include by default will not return anything, the file has to return something to compare too.

Comment: var_dump prints true ... here is the output from running the script: `.:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/PEAR bool(true) INCLUDE FAILED \n`

Comment: That just means the file exists. Also, your include statement should be `((include '/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php') == 'OK')` and the file that you're including actually **has to return the value 'OK'** (`return 'OK';`) in order for that conditional statement to pass.

Comment: Just changed the if statement to: `if ((include '/usr/lib/php/HTTP/OAuth.php') == 'OK') {`   It still prints the same line: `.:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/PEAR bool(true) INCLUDE FAILED \n`

Comment: Have you tried putting something in the other file such as `var_dump('The file is included.');` to test if code in the other file is being run?

Comment: Looks like it is indeed including the file in question ... here's output now: `.:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/PEAR bool(true) string(21) "The file is included." INCLUDE FAILED \n `  I guess thats a good sign ... but doesnt give me alot of confidence in the php interpreter :(  In any case, thank you for the feedback @animuson and I appreciate any other advice you can provide.